# What is this SMD for on a SZBK07?

Tags: buck, surface-mount

I purchased a SZBK07 CCCV Step Down Buck Converter and I was hoping to remove the TRIMPOT and replace with a potentiometer how ever there was a Orange SMD thing bridged between the 2 and 1 pin's on the PCB, This has fallen of and I can not find it. I replaced the Trimpot with a  potentiometer  of 100k (Same as trimpot W104) it how ever smokes and the output voltage does not adjust, I tried a 330ohm resistor in place of the unknown SMD but this just makes the LED light on the buck not turn on and output is 1.5v non adjustable. The Potentiometer is for the VCC as in the diagram below.

[image]
IMAGE OF SMD (White in this case directly below the orange wire on the two pins)

DIAGRAM OF SZKB07
[image]

---

Here is another picture:

[image]

Comment: If the component was orange/brown, and jn the picture white, think it must be a SMD capacitor. Does the potmeter have the same power rating as the trimpot?

Comment: Without a better picture this may just be a metal "jumper", however your diagram is just an example circuit for the LM25116 out of the datasheet, and isn't representative of the board. If we knew what those connectors are and where they go, this may be easier to answer.

Comment: @Huisman Yes both were 100k ohm

Comment: @RonBeyer Sorry I will try and find a better picture, As I am missing the SMD I can't take a picture of it sorry.

Comment: @KieranRead 100kW? :D ... Check the power rating (in watts) instead of resistor value.

Comment: It is a SMD cap. The trimpot is likely used as feedback resistor and the cap to smooth the noise created by the swiper. I wonder if the absence of that cap caused the pot to smoke.

Comment: @Huisman  think so as someone else suggested a resistor I tried a 300ohm and it did not smoke but did not control the output and stayed at 1.5v, How would I figure out the cap value please? I asked the people who sold it to me but they did no have any idea :(

Comment: There is no way to find the cap value without having one in your possession, smt capacitor colors mean very little, especially if you don't know the manufacturer. Even if you do, usually one has to de solder it from the board and measure the value.

Comment: BTW, i'm sure the trimpot is used as feedback resistor because two wires/trace back to pin 10 and indirectly to pin 8&9. I don't think the value of the lost cap was big (about 1nF or smaller??) as it would affect the compensation network at pin 8&9. AGAIN: I really doubt losing that cap made the SMPS go weird: the SMPS must have been damaged due to a different cause.

Comment: @VoltageSpike Thanks for your input I will have to look harder to find the cap but had no marking on it

Comment: @Huisman I see I will see if I can find the cap and get the same trimpot and see if it works hopefully it will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was testing this part.

It is a capacitor, 580 nF.

[image]